# C - Problema al usar fprintf() para imprimir en un archivo de texto

Tags: c, archivo

tengo un problema al usar `fprintf()` en c.
Tengo el siguiente archivo de texto llamado `clientes.txt`:

```
Pedro Pérez 7569984 0 500000 100000
Luisa García 8987565 0 1.500000 250000
Josefa Cardenas 1565988 0 2700000 580000
María González 5456748 0 850000 0
```

Que son el Nombre, Apellido, Cedula, Estado de Cuenta(Activa o Inactiva), Monto Disponible, y Monto Deudor.

La idea es pedirle al usuario la cedula, verificar si está registrada en `clientes.txt` y luego cambiar el estado de la cuenta de 0 (Inactiva) a 1 (Activa).

Para eso hice el siguiente codigo:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    // Variable para almacenar los datos
    char nombre[15], apellido[15];
    int ci, estadoCuenta, ciInp;
    float monDisp, monDeu;
    
    FILE * F = fopen("clientes.txt","r+");
    
    // Solicitar al usuario su numero de Cedula
    printf("Ingrese su cedula >>> ");
    scanf("%d", &ciInp);
    
    //Bucle Mientras no se llegue al final del archivo
    while (feof(F) == 0){
        // Fscanf para almacenar los datos del archivo en sus respectivas variables    
        fscanf(F, "%s %s %d %d %f %f", nombre, apellido, &ci, &estadoCuenta, &monDisp, &monDeu);
        if (ci == ciInp){
            // Se detiene en buble si se encuentra la Cedula
            printf("\nLa Cedula Coincide");
            break;
        }
    }
    // Se imprime en el archivo
    fprintf(F, "%s %s %d 0 %f %f\n", nombre, apellido, ci, estadoCuenta, monDisp, monDeu);
    fclose(F);
    return 0;
}
```

El programa corre sin errores y verifica con exito si el numero de cedula, pero por alguna razon el archivo se mantiene sin cambios, ya no se que hacer...

Espero que puedan ayudarme, de antemano muchas gracias...

Answer (score 0):

Es porque el archivo está abierto solamente para leer.  Cambiar la linea a:

```
 FILE * F = fopen("clientes.txt","r+");
```

para leer y escribir.

Comment: Ha dale, gracias por decime, en realidad ese no es el problema ya que el programa principal es mas largo, pero hice este para explicarlo mejor.

Comment: ya lo edite para no causar confuciones